# ConTeXt SlideWithSteps usage

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I am trying to use SlideWithSteps using the following piece of code

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides]
\usemodule[SlideWithSteps]
\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
    author={name},
    date={10 July, 2016},
  ]

\starttext
\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}
Write whatever you want.

\SlideWithSteps{3}{
\SlideTitle {The third slide}

\Step{1}{
\startitemize
    \starthead {1}
    para 1
    \startitemize 
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \stopitemize
\stopitemize
}

\Step{2}{
{\vskip 2pt}
\startitemize
    \starthead {1}
    para 1
    \startitemize 
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \stopitemize
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

When I compile, I obtain the following error:

```
tex error on line 33 in file      /Users/kaarthik/Documents/contexttest/SlideWithSteps/example.tex: ! Undefined control sequence
```

Line 33 is `\SlideWithSteps{3}{`

Any help with this issue is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a MWE, is it?

Comment: @DG' What is a MWE?

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that we can run to show the problem?  Most likely you have forgotten to load something that defined the `SlideWithSteps` environment.

Comment: @user62089 The SlideWithSteps module (http://wiki.contextgarden.net/SlideWithSteps) uses the `\eject` command to flush a page after each step but the command doesn’t exist anymore in MkIV and you have to replace it with `\page` to get the module working.

Answer (score 1):

Making Wolfgang's comment into an answer:

> The SlideWithSteps module ([wiki.contextgarden.net/SlideWithSteps](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/SlideWithSteps)) uses the `\eject` command to flush a page after each step but the command doesn’t exist anymore in MkIV and you have to replace it with `\page` to get the module working.

I just fixed it in the Wiki, so you can straight copy-paste from there.